# How to call XML API in Python

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest, travelport-api, xmlapi2

I am learning Python and want to build a small project to query flight price data. The airline provided the API, but it's XML format. how do I call it?
Very appreciated.

https://www.csair.com/en/czadscale/2019/20190522_0/index.html